# what flavor of linux is popularly used in companies running web applications?

Tags: linux, web-development

i lack some knowledge in linux and was wondering what flavor of linux is popularly used at companies who operate web applications. i know there are alot of them and i worry that if i learn one flavor and get hired at a company who offers another i might not qualify. aside from the user interface are they the same in general? as in commands intered and installation process?

thanks

i am a current user of mac

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All distros of linux are alike and all are different. With that said, if you understand one real well, you can get around in any of them well enough and you can look up the rest easily.
What a company uses is not going to be based around the applications they run, or just the fact that they run web apps. For the most part, they will be run by whatever those in charge of setting things up were comfortable with at the time. Some companies will choose distros that offer support options (like red hat) and others will not care. There really is no good answer to your question as it is very subjective - everyone will have an answer based on their experience, not necessarily based on all the companies out there and all the available distros in use.

Comment: Agreed. Though, Redhat based distro's seem to have a greater uptake in the corporate world I think, mainly because of those support options.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking Companies running web applications, you will probably find that Microsoft and Java have a majority share. That is if you meant big companies. Coldfusion is also very big in multi-nationals in australia.

If you are looking for enterprise linux, most will use Red Hat enterprise or use Unix instead such as a BSD variant like Open BSD (Unix). Bsd of FreeBSD unix is what the Mac operating system is now based on.

Most Linux flavours will be pretty much the same in command line stuff. If you learn one, you will have a good grounding in others.

Comment: Actually, Apache has always had a much higher market share than IIS. Currently, it's 3:1 according to Netcraft's numbers at http://news.netcraft.com/archives/2011/03/09/march-2011-web-server-survey.html - Netcraft doesn't report OS anymore that I can find, but it would be hard to convince anyone that even 10% of production Apache installations are on Windows.